# How can I create this effect with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have HTML that CANNOT be changed whatsoever and I have a certain design that I'm aiming for. And I cannot use JS for this yet. [image]

Just a note too, the container is actually the parent of all the other elements on the screen. However, the reason I drew like that is because that's the look i want, and if possible, as I scroll down the only thing that scrolls is element 3 and 4, and 3 and 1 stay fixed. At the moment the container is a flex box. The CSS that I have doesn't really do what I need it to do, but here it is:

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

#intro {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  order: 2;
}

#nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  order: 1;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 65%;
  order: 3
}

article {
  order: 4;
}

footer {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <article>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></li>
  </article>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does the image have an error in that <div> should be element #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as I scroll down the only thing that scrolls is element 3 and 4

Using `position: fixed` we can make `nav`/`intro`/`footer` stay while `content`/`article` scroll.

The `align-items: flex-end;` on `content`/`article` will keep them right aligned, and `flex-grow: 1` on `container`/`content` will make them fill the remaining space.

Stack snippet

```css
html {
  display: flex;                 /*  IE min-height bug fix  */
}

body {
  width: 100%;                   /*  using IE bug fix it need a width  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;             /*  instead using precent all over  */
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15%;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);     /*  make up for footer  */
  background-color: red;
}

#intro {
  position: fixed;
  left: 15%;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);     /*  make up for footer  */
  background-color: yellow;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 65%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

article {
  margin-bottom: 30px;           /*  make up for footer  */
}

article li {
  list-style: none;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">Intro</section>
  <div id="content">
    Content along with below article that will scroll and leave "Nav"/"Intro" fixed. <br>
    Content along with below article that will scroll and leave "Nav"/"Intro" fixed. <br>
  </div>
  <aside id="nav">Nav</aside>
  <article>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></li>
  </article>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: hello, here is another approach with position:sticky and some margins around the boxes https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MENOEE

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Just set the `article` to have the same width as the `#content` and set the 
`justify-content:flex-end` on the `#container`.

```
#container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height: 100%;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}

article {
    order: 4;
    width:65%;
}
```

---

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#intro {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  order: 2;
}

#nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  order: 1;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 65%;
  order: 3
}

article {
  order: 4;
  width: 65%;
  background: cyan;
}

footer {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <article>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></li>
  </article>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```